# Unable to load preference pane

Tags: preferences

I installed TCPBlock and whenever I try to open the TCPBlock preference pane I get the error:  "Unable to load TCPBlock preference pane".  Does anyone know what might cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TCPBlock and OS X 10.9

[Comments associated](http://tcpblock.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/tcpblock/#comments) with the last TCPBlock blog update suggest there may be problems with OS X 10.9, Mavericks, and tools like [Clean My Mac](http://tcpblock.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/tcpblock/#comment-275).

### Console

Use the [Console.app](http://www.dssw.co.uk/support/#console) utility included in Mac OS X to look for error messages. Console.app is located in: **/Applications/Utilities**

With Console.app running, try opening TCPBlock preference pane again. You will likely see a little flurry of messages.

Possible problems include the preference pane being built for 32-bit Macs only, and missing frameworks or dependencies.

Comment: I didn't find much, but I ended up doing a search using EasyFind (since OS X search doesn't find sh!t) and deleted some remaining files, reintsalled, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a search using [EasyFind](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html), since OS X search doesn't find much, and deleted some remaining files, reintsalled, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

TCPBlock seems to have been discontinued an doesn't work since El Capitan. https://www.tripmode.ch/ looks like a good alternative.